# how to show the following two inequalities? (using Euler method)

Tags: inequality

I'm stuck again on a numerical Problem. In the course numerical solution of ODE we already introduced the Euler method and now we have to show based on this Cauchy Problem:
$y'(t)=y(t)^2$

$y(0)=1$

the two inequalities:

[image]

[image]

From the assistant we got the hint to use induction in both cases.
For the first one I did until now the following:
for $n=0$, $t_0=0$ and $y_0=1\leq\frac{1}{1-0}\leq\frac{1}{1-t_0}$

now I assumed it holds for $n$ and I want to show it for $n+1$
by definition of the euler method it follows:

$y_{n+1}=y_n+h_nf(y_n,t_n)$, with $f(y_n,t_n)=y_n(t)^2$

$y_{n+1}\leq\frac{1}{1-t_n}+(t_{n+1}-t_n)(\frac{1}{1-t_n})^2=\frac{1-t_n+t_{n+1}-t_n}{(1-t_n)^2}$

$=\frac{1}{1-t_n}\frac{1-2t_n+t_{n+1}}{1-t_n}$

because $t_{n+1}-t_n=h_n\geq0$ it follows that $\frac{1}{1-t_n}\leq\frac{1}{1-t_{n+1}}$

and hence $y_{n+1}\leq\frac{1}{1-t_{n+1}}\frac{1-2t_n+t_{n+1}}{1-t_{n+1}}$

now if I could show that $\frac{1-2t_n+t_{n+1}}{1-t_{n+1}}\leq1$ it would be finished, but this is not true because:

$\frac{1-2t_n+t_{n+1}}{1-t_{n+1}}\leq1$ <=> $1-2t_n+t_{n+1}\leq1-t_{n+1}$ <=> $1-2t_n\leq 1-2t_{n+1}$

<=> $t_n\geq t_{n+1}$ which is obviously wrong.
Could someone give me a good hint how to solve it or where I made a mistake.

The second case I find more complicated. first of all: we already showed in c) that $t_n\leq 1$ and hence $\forall a\geq 0 : t_n \leq 1+a$, so what should I write there?
I also noticed that the first derivative of $y$ is always positive and with $y(0)=1$ it follows that $y(t)\geq0$ $\forall t\geq0$ and increasing, so $\epsilon \geq0$ and we can drop the absolute value. But then I'm stuck, I don't know how to use the written hint to write $\epsilon_n$ in an other way.
I would appreciate if someone could give me some hints. Thanks a lot.